# Bootstrap Collapse toggle show/hide in 3 column WITHOUT an accordion

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've got this problem. I need to use a js show & hide function to do what the Bootstrap accordion function does but I can't use an accordion because I need the buttons to be in a 3 column group & have the collapse to go into full width.
Currently when I toggle one it shows & hides that one. I need it to show the current one & hide the rest.
Help!

http://jsfiddle.net/Lowdl/pruggwqk/2/

```
    <div class="itl">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4" id="accordion">
<button type="button" class="btnRed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseInvest" data-parent="#accordion" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#collapseInvest">Find out more</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 green">
<button type="button" class="btnGreen" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTrust" data-parent="#accordion" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#collapseTrust">Find out more</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<button type="button" class="btnRed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseLead" data-parent="#accordion" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#collapseLead">Find out more</button>
</div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>

<div id="collapseInvest" class="collapse">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut id dolor lorem. Phasellus a nisl sit amet est finibus tempor. Mauris sit amet massa sagittis, gravida tellus in, venenatis sem. Suspendisse efficitur efficitur varius. Cras euismod nisi ex, non lobortis risus dignissim vel.</P>

  </div>

<div id="collapseTrust" class="collapse">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut id dolor lorem. Phasellus a nisl sit amet est finibus tempor. Mauris sit amet massa sagittis, gravida tellus in, venenatis sem. Suspendisse efficitur efficitur varius. Cras euismod nisi ex, non lobortis risus dignissim vel.</p>

  </div>

  <div id="collapseLead" class="collapse">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut id dolor lorem. Phasellus a nisl sit amet est finibus tempor. Mauris sit amet massa sagittis, gravida tellus in, venenatis sem. Suspendisse efficitur efficitur varius. Cras euismod nisi ex, non lobortis risus dignissim vel.</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group. Is that what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/alexqoliveira/pruggwqk/6/

```
    <div class="col-md-4"  >
<button type="button" class="btnRed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseInvest" data-parent="#accordion" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#collapseInvest">Find out more</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 green">
<button type="button" class="btnGreen" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTrust" data-parent="#accordion" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#collapseTrust">Find out more</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<button type="button" class="btnRed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseLead" data-parent="#accordion" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#collapseLead">Find out more</button>
</div>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
<div id="collapseInvest" class="collapse in">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut id dolor lorem. Phasellus a nisl sit amet est finibus tempor. Mauris sit amet massa sagittis, gravida tellus in, venenatis sem. Suspendisse efficitur efficitur varius. Cras euismod nisi ex, non lobortis risus dignissim vel.</P>

  </div>

<div id="collapseTrust" class="collapse">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut id dolor lorem. Phasellus a nisl sit amet est finibus tempor. Mauris sit amet massa sagittis, gravida tellus in, venenatis sem. Suspendisse efficitur efficitur varius. Cras euismod nisi ex, non lobortis risus dignissim vel.</p>

  </div>

  <div id="collapseLead" class="collapse">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut id dolor lorem. Phasellus a nisl sit amet est finibus tempor. Mauris sit amet massa sagittis, gravida tellus in, venenatis sem. Suspendisse efficitur efficitur varius. Cras euismod nisi ex, non lobortis risus dignissim vel.</p>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that's what I want. I just need all collapses closed by default. Only when one is selected does it drop down. & vice versa. That is very close though. Thank!

Comment: Just remove the class 'in' on the tag div 'collapseInvest'

Comment: Perfect! Thank you guys so much. Working just like it should.